# How can I force a MariaDB Database Drop?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB 10.0 Instance with what appears to be a corrupted database. I want to delete it but get an error when I try to alter or inspect it.

Is there a way to manually delete a database?

This is what I have tried:

```
unknown [web]> drop database web;
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    165
Current database: web

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
ERROR: Can't connect to the server
```

Other databases and tables work correctly.

This error returns immediately.

I am able to list the tables in the database by adding `innodb_force_recovery = 4` to `my.cnf` but am not able to drop any tables or the database in read only mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a corrupted database. I would first check and repair the database by

```
./client/mysqlcheck [OPTIONS] --databases DB1
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqlcheck/

If it does not help, I will also try the following

- backup the database(s)
- remove MariaDB instance
- reinstall MariaDB
- restore backup database(s)